# Create Pull Request from another Pull Request

Tags: git, github

I have a pull request named `feature_A`.
I want to create another pull request named `feature_B`.
But `feature_B` is **almost the same** as `feature_A`.
So I want to create pull request from branch `feature_A` and edit a little bit from there.
Is it possible to do like that and how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to go to your branch:

```sh
git checkout feature_A
```

Then you create the new branch to make the small changes:

```sh
git checkout -b feature_B
```

At the end you push the branch with the new changes into the repository and you can create your PR with the [GitHub CLI](https://github.com/cli/cli).

```sh
git commit -a
git push --set-upstream origin feature_B
gh pr create
```

Comment: Ah I see. But need to change the HEAD first, so I have a clean commit